# In Django, do I need to add a db_index to object_id when using a GenericForeignKey?

Tags: django, generic-foreign-key

Django's sample code at https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

```
content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

shows object_id without `db_index=True`

although `object_id` probably will be used for join operation.

Is `db_index=True` assumed because of some hidden code regarding GFK? 
Or should I include it when I need it?

Comment: There is no JOIN operation here; it's not a real foreign key, it's a GFK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you should make the `object_id` field indexable by yourself.
As of 1.9, Django [doesn't do](https://github.com/django/django/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=db_index+path%3Adjango%2Fcontrib%2Fcontenttypes&type=Code) any magic on that.

Comment: I've checked the 1.5 version - still the same. So I doubt it has ever done that.